# Difference between Diffuse and Suffuse

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

The words *diffuse* and *suffuse* have almost similar meaning, both of them can be interpreted as "spread over something".

What is the difference between them? And which one should be used in which context?

Comment: Hello. I must point out that It is an easily searchable discussion. Look it up and come back with specifics of what you don't understand.

Comment: Look up in any dictionary, please!

Comment: http://the-difference-between.com/suffuse/diffuse

Answer (score 2):

To **diffuse** is to spread something.

To **suffuse** is to spread something over something else.

> Some music had to be played in order to diffuse the discomfort.
>
> What more could be needed to suffuse the world with the deepest meaning and beauty?

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/diffuse?s=t

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/suffuse?s=t

Comment: Helpful note for the OP: keep in mind the roots of these words and they'll be indelibly etched in your vocabulary. Specifically, *dif* and *sub*.

Comment: If I heard the first one I would always assume you meant defuse. Reading the sentence with diffuse really makes me think there was just a couple of people who were uncomfortable and the music playing ensured that now everyone is.

Comment: @DRF It's called humor.

Comment: @ricky Ahh ok fair enough. It makes it somewhat tricky when you're using it with the idea of explicating the meaning though.

Comment: @DRF Well. My philosophy is since we all have brains we might as well use them. When someone is baffled by something, the logical thing to do is point it out and ask - the way you did earlier. When someone doesn't quite "get" something, again, why not ask someone else to clarify it? That's how conversations become, not merely informative, but entertaining as well.

Comment: @DRF Oh, and by the way, " there was just a couple of people who were uncomfortable and the music playing ensured that now everyone is": thank you for that. Love the image. Great way to put it!